# inconsistency with selenium library

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, web

I'm trying to create a selenium code in my computer but it is not working. The code is:

```
    from selenium import webdriver
    from pathlib import Path

    chromedriver_path:str = Path(__file__).absolute().parent / 'chromedriver'
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver_path)
    driver.get("www.google.com")
```

When I try to run it, it shows me the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/macklee/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/driver_finder.py", line 38, in get_path
    path = SeleniumManager().driver_location(options) if path is None else path
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/macklee/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/selenium_manager.py", line 87, in driver_location
    browser = options.capabilities["browserName"]
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'PosixPath' object has no attribute 'capabilities'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/macklee/Desktop/Computer science/Studies/Python/Paulla gomes project/navagation.py", line 5, in 
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver_path)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/macklee/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 45, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "/Users/macklee/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chromium/webdriver.py", line 49, in __init__
    self.service.path = DriverFinder.get_path(self.service, options)
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/macklee/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/driver_finder.py", line 40, in get_path
    msg = f"Unable to obtain driver for {options.capabilities['browserName']} using Selenium Manager."
                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'PosixPath' object has no attribute 'capabilities'
```

Comment: Try this `path = Path(__file__).absolute().parent / "chromedriver.exe"` or try reinstalling the selenium package.

Comment: @sourin_karmakar Aside from the presence of ".exe" on the end, how is your suggestion any different from what they used?

Answer (score 0):

By default, `Chrome()` assumes that its first argument is an `options` object.

You need to specify that you're passing the chromedriver path, not an options object.

You do that by putting `executable_path=` in fromnt of the argument.

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chromedriver_path)
```

Comment: It gave me another error: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/macklee/Desktop/Computer science/Studies/Python/Paulla gomes project/navagation.py", line 5, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chromedriver_path)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: WebDriver.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'executable_path'

Answer (score 0):

You can try this out

```py
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium import webdriver

service = Service()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service)
driver.get("www.google.com")
```

Service will autodetect the chrome version and download suitable chromedriver. This will happen in the background. You might need selenium>=4.10